# Allowing only certain branches to PR merge to main(master) branch

Tags: github

I'm looking for methods to protect `main` branch by preventing branches except `dev` branch from pull request merge to `main` branch. But I could not find a way to it. Is there any way for it? or is it possible using Github Action?

Comment: have you managed to do this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible out of the box. You can write a workflow that runs on a PR and fails if the source branch is not `dev`. Then add this workflow as a required check in the branch protection rule for the `main` branch.

Answer (score 18):

I took Rob Bos's advice and created a workflow to do this, here is what I have in my `enforcer.yaml` file

```
name: 'Check Branch'

on:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  check_branch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check branch
        if: github.base_ref == 'main' && github.head_ref != 'dev'
        run: |
          echo "ERROR: You can only merge to main from dev."
          exit 1
```

Then I have the workflow `check_branch` as a required status check in the branch protection rule for my `main` branch. Attempting a pull request into `main` from any branch other than `dev` fails.