# How to protect branches' merge

Tags: git, github, branch, branching-and-merging

I need to protect a main branch from other branches on the organization,
ex. have an alpha branch, beta branch, development and main, and I must be force to push from the development branch to the main branch, the unique branch allowed to send to main is the development, so, need to protect the allowance to protect a branch from the rest of the branches in the repository.

I need to protect a main branch from other branches on the organization

Comment: Are you referring to branch protections for a git repository hosted on github?

Comment: I just want to protect a branch, that is just able to receive from from a selected branch

Comment: This is very likely a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71120146/184546). The summary is you enable branch protection on `main`, and then use a status check which runs for every Pull Request, and only passes if the source branch is `development`.